# Ejecutar una sentencia por lotes en mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una sentencia por lotes desde un archivo en mysql y me el error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '> /home/carlos/Dropbox/APUNTES/MYSQL/lotes2.txt' at line 1

La sentencia en el archivo es :

```
Select * from pet > /home/carlos/Dropbox/APUNTES/MYSQL/lotes2.txt;
```

El error me lo da cuando intento que la salida la escriba en el archivo `lotes2.txt`. Si solo hago `Select` me funciona.

No es un problema de rutas ya que el archivo donde esta la sentencia esta en el mismo directorio que `lotes2.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No podes usar el operador de la terminal para canalizar la salida a un archivo porque, *"no estas en la terminal"*, estas en el entorno del comando `mysql`.

Para escribir en un archivo el resultado de tu consulta tenes que utilizar la sintaxis [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

#### Ejemplo:

```
Select * from pet INTO OUTFILE "/home/carlos/Dropbox/APUNTES/MYSQL/lotes2.txt";
```

---

Si al ejecutar este comando obtenes como resultado el error:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Significa que no podes escribir el archivo en otro lugar que no sea el configurado en [`secure-file-priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv).

Entonces ahora tenes dos opciones:

1. **Exportar al directorio configurado**.

   Para saber cual es dicho directorio podes hacer:

   ```
   mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
   +------------------------------------------------+
   | @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv                      |
   +------------------------------------------------+
   | [PATH/AL/DIRECTORIO/CONFIGURADO]               |
   +------------------------------------------------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
2. **Desactivar la seguridad.**

   Para esto tenes que:

   - Buscar y editar el archivo `my.cnf` (*en Windows `my.ini`*).
   - Editar/agregar:

     ```
     [mysqld_safe]
     [mysqld]
     secure-file-priv = ""
     ```
   - Reiniciar MySQL.
   - Validar que la configuración funciono

     ```
     mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
     ```